# sql azure connection pool configuration and settings

Tags: azure, tomcat, jakarta-ee, azure-sql-database

I am currently testing a web application with JMeter and discovered that in some cases under high load some HTTP requests are hanging and not receiving a response.  This leads me to think that the connection pool is being exhausted.

How can I view the current SQL Azure settings that are being used?  How would I configure the pool size ?

I have looked in the documentation but am not seeing any how this would be done.  My connection is set up in context.xml as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/sqlazure"
auth="Container"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxIdle="30"
```

Below are the options specified in my jdbc connection URL

```
database
encrypt
trustServerCertificate
hostNameInCertificate
removeAbandonedTimeout
logAbandoned
```

Based on my JMeter config, I am seeing for the failed requests the following:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Socket closed
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which connection pool are you using - DBCP or Tomcat's connection pool?

Comment: good question, how would i check ?  I would say it's Tomcat's since the web app is running on a Tomcat instance in the Azure environment

Answer (score 0):

Copy Database connection String from Azure SQL JDBC tab In Azure portal.
[image: Exmple of JDBC connection string]